# how to render from frame before 0 (minus frame)?

Tags: keyframes

I have an animation that I messed up and had to start it from frame -20, but when I render it starts from frame 0, how do I render from there. Thanks

Comment: you need to move all your keyframes, or maybe there's a script to move the whole timeline?

Comment: You can allow negative frames by checking in: Edit>>Preferences>>Animation>>Timeline>>"Allow Negative Frames"

Comment: @FFeller yes but it doesn't seem to allow you to start a render before frame 0

Comment: @moonboots You can't type in a negative start frame, but if you click on a negative frame in the timeline and hit ctrl+home, it works fine. (I always use this method, thats why I didn't realized this).